# AWS Config bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to deploy a template through CloudFormation. AWS Config with a S3 bucket but I am getting an incorrect policy, `unable to write to bucket` error.

does anyone know the proper template and code for this action I am trying to complete?

Please help

Here is my code. I am getting `incorrect bucket policy can't write to bucket` error.

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "Template for a startup company looking to move their services to the cloud",
    "Resources": {
        "ResumeConfigRecorder": {
            "Type": "AWS::Config::ConfigurationRecorder",
            "Properties": {
                "Name": "ResumeConfigRecorder",
                "RecordingGroup": {
                    "AllSupported": true
                },
                "RoleARN": "arn:aws:iam::451750859333:role/aws-service-role/config.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForConfig"
            }
        },
        "ResumeConfigDeliveryChannel": {
            "Type": "AWS::Config::DeliveryChannel",
            "Properties": {
                "ConfigSnapshotDeliveryProperties": {
                    "DeliveryFrequency": "Three_Hours"
                },
                "Name": "ResumeConfigDeliveryChannel",
                "S3BucketName": "config-resumematch",
                "S3KmsKeyArn": {
                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                        "ConfigKey",
                        "Arn"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "ConfigBucket": {
            "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
            "Properties": {
                "AccessControl": "Private",
                "BucketName": "config-resumematch",
                "BucketEncryption": {
                    "ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration": [
                        {
                            "BucketKeyEnabled": true,
                            "ServerSideEncryptionByDefault": {
                                "KMSMasterKeyID": {
                                    "Ref": "ConfigKey"
                                },
                                "SSEAlgorithm": "aws:kms"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Tags": [
                    {
                        "Key": "Name",
                        "Value": "ConfigBucket"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "ConfigBucketPolicy": {
            "Type": "AWS::S3::BucketPolicy",
            "Properties": {
                "Bucket": {
                    "Ref": "ConfigBucket"
                },
                "PolicyDocument": {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Sid": "AWSConfigBucketPermissionsCheck",
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Principal": {
                                "Service": "config.amazonaws.com"
                            },
                            "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::config-resumematch",
                            "Condition": {
                                "StringEquals": {
                                    "AWS:SourceAccount": "451750859333"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "Sid": "AWSConfigBucketExistenceCheck",
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Principal": {
                                "Service": "config.amazonaws.com"
                            },
                            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
                            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::config-resumematch",
                            "Condition": {
                                "StringEquals": {
                                    "AWS:SourceAccount": "451750859333"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "Sid": "AWSConfigBucketDelivery",
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Principal": {
                                "Service": "config.amazonaws.com"
                            },
                            "Action": [
                                "s3:PutObject*"
                            ],        
                            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::config-resumematch/AWSLogs/451750859333/Config/*",
                            "Condition": {
                                "StringEquals": {
                                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control",
                                    "AWS:SourceAccount": "451750859333"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "ConfigKey": {
            "Type": "AWS::KMS::Key",
            "Properties": {
                "Description": "Key to encrypt config records in S3",
                "Enabled": true,
                "KeyPolicy": {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Id": "config-key-1",
                    "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Sid": "Enable IAM Permissions",
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Principal": {
                                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::451750859333:root"
                            },
                            "Action": "kms:*",
                            "Resource": "*"
                        },
                        {
                            "Sid": "Allow administration of the key",
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Principal": {
                                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::451750859333:user/ecargle"
                            },
                            "Action": [
                                "kms:Put*",
                                "kms:Create*",
                                "kms:Describe*",
                                "kms:Enable*",
                                "kms:List*",
                                "kms:Get*",
                                "kms:Delete*"
                            ],
                            "Resource": "*"
                        },
                        {
                            "Sid": "Allow config to use KMS key",
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Principal": {
                                "Service": "config.amazonaws.com"
                            },
                            "Action": [
                                "kms:Encrypt*",
                                "kms:Decrypt*"
                            ],
                            "Resource": "*"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "KeySpec": "SYMMETRIC_DEFAULT",
                "KeyUsage": "ENCRYPT_DECRYPT",
                "Tags": [
                    {
                        "Key": "Name",
                        "Value": "ConfigKey"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "ConfigKeyAlias": {
            "Type": "AWS::KMS::Alias",
            "Properties": {
                "AliasName": "alias/configKey",
                "TargetKeyId": {
                    "Ref": "ConfigKey"
                }
            }
        },
        "ResumeConfigRuleEC2": {
            "DependsOn" : "ResumeConfigRecorder",
            "Type": "AWS::Config::ConfigRule",
            "Properties": {
                "ConfigRuleName": "ResumeMatchConfigRuleEC2",
                "Description": "rule to monitor the configuration of AWS resources",
                "Scope": {
                    "ComplianceResourceTypes": [
                        "AWS::EC2::Volume"
                    ]
                },
                "Source": {
                    "Owner": "AWS",
                    "SourceIdentifier": "EC2_EBS_ENCRYPTION_BY_DEFAULT"
                }
            }
        },
        "ResumeConfigRuleS3": {
            "DependsOn" :  "ResumeConfigRecorder",
            "Type": "AWS::Config::ConfigRule",
            "Properties": {
                "ConfigRuleName": "ResumeMatchConfigRuleS3",
                "Description": "rule to monitor the configuration of AWS resources",
                "Scope": {
                    "ComplianceResourceTypes": [
                        "AWS::S3::Bucket"
                        
                    ]
                },
                "Source": {
                    "Owner": "AWS",
                    "SourceIdentifier": "ELB_LOGGING_ENABLED"
                }
            }
        },
        "ResumeConfigRuleELB": {
            "DependsOn" : "ResumeConfigRecorder",
            "Type": "AWS::Config::ConfigRule",
            "Properties": {
                "ConfigRuleName": "ResumeMatchConfigRuleELB",
                "Description": "rule to monitor the configuration of AWS resources",
                "Scope": {
                    "ComplianceResourceTypes": [
                        "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer"
                    ]
                },
                "Source": {
                    "Owner": "AWS",
                    "SourceIdentifier": "ELB_LOGGING_ENABLED"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "getting an incorrect policy" -- can you show us your policy and the _exact_ error message? Also, please tell us what you are doing when you receive this error. For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The error is incorrect bucket policy, unable to Write to bucket. I gave config the putbucket permissions and getbucketacl permissions. Also tried the putobjectacl permissions and that also did not work

Comment: That's a lot of code you have provided! Please Edit your question and reduce the code to show only enough to demonstrate your particular situation. Also, please tell us what you are doing when the error occurs -- does it happen as soon as you create the CloudFormation stack, or is it only later when you try to use AWS Config? Or, if you took this code from somewhere, can you point us to where you got it?